# Display a form in Qt

Tags: qt, qt4

This should be very easy.
I'm using **Qt Creator** and I have made a `Qt Gui Application` (That had `main.h`, `main.ui` and `main.cpp`)

I just created a `Qt Designer Form Class` that also has a header file, ui, and a class.
I have made an action inside my `main.cpp` called *ShowSecondForm*:

```
void Main::ShowSecondForm()
{

}
```

Everytime I execute `ShowSecondForm();` I want the second form to be displayed.
What do I put inside so my form will open?
Also, is is possible to pass a string to the form while opening it? Like `ShowSecondForm(const QString&)`?

*Some notes that may help you:*

- I would like to have 2 forms opened at the same time.
- It will also be a class as it will compute different things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're opening one form from another, you might want to do something like this:

```
m_form = new MyForm (this);
m_form->show();
```

Here you first create the form object, and then show it. Note `this` is passed as a parent - when a parent form is destroyed, children will be closed and destroyed automatically. That also means you don't need to bother cleaning up in destructor. If you need to open several forms, you will need an object for each of them.

```
m_form1 = new MyForm (this);
m_form1->show();
m_form2 = new MyForm (this);
m_form2->show();
```

Finally, there are many ways to pass a string to the form. It's your form, so you may want to modify it's constructor, so that it would accept string upon creation, like `m_form = new MyForm ("Some string", this);` Or you may want to add a property to your form. Sometimes, you may also want to use `QObject`'s built-in property system, take a look at [QObject::setProperty()](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.7/qobject.html#setProperty) and [QObject::property()](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.7/qobject.html#property) functions.

Comment: Hello Septagram!
m_form = new MyForm (this); will create a NEW form. I have created a form using the QtDesigner. All I want is display the form I have created. The form is called form2.ui and it has a form2.h and a form2.cpp file because is not just a form but also a class.

Comment: In designer, you created a class. A class is like a blueprint for forms you actually use. But to use it you need to create an _object_ of that class. Take a look at myform2.h and substitute MyForm in my example for class name from form2.h (I guess it's Form2). Then a form you made with designer will be created and opened.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect [this tutorial](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.7/designer-calculatorform.html) might be helpful. Presumably you have a main.ui, a main.h and a main.cpp.

Run the `uic` program over your main.ui file, to generate your ui_main.h header (if you're not using qmake), but otherwise the basic setup is in that tutorial.

Comment: I think that the example uses only one form..
When I created my second form, qt automatically created all the files,declarations and methods needed. Im just asking how to display the second form I have created using an action. Check ShowSecondForm(); I want everytime this function is executed, the second form to be displayed.

Comment: The ui system simply attaches the layout and such onto an existing QWidget, so if you want to be alternating to of them, feed each one a different QWidget and show/hide them.