# Displaying a second form in Qt

Tags: qt, forms

I know this question has been asked a few time, (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4436511/display-a-form-in-qt)

I am trying to open an existing form in my Qt C++ project.
it needs to be a subform instead of QDialog box.

both forms have a .ui, .h and .cpp file with them.

in my mwindowtest.cpp I have

```
//this is used to handle the button click to open the new form
connect(btnConnect, SIGNAL(click()), this, SLOT(openNewWindow()));
```

for function is:

```
void mWindowTest::openNewWindow(){

   mForm = new dialog (this);
   mForm->show();

}
```

in my mwindowtest.cpp I have:

```
#include <dialog.h>  //second form
class dialog;
```

I'm now getting the error mForm was not declared in this scope. 
but I am not sure what to declare mForm as in my Header file.

any tips would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example you will have memory leak since each time button btnConnect is clicked you will reallocate memory for your form, without deleting the previous first.

Concerning your problem, we need to know how is declare dialog in dialog.h to be able to really help you.
In your mywindowtest.cpp you have included the file and redefined the class. Try to put

```
class dialog
```

in your hpp file and

```
#include <dialog.h>
```

in your cpp file.

Hope that helps

**Edit:**

In your slot:

```
delete mForm;
mForm = new dialog();
dialog->show();
```

It's the minimum to avoid memory leaks; And don't forget to delete mForm in MyWindowTest destructor too if not null;

Comment: I already had the include in my .cpp. I did however add class dialog to the namespace of mywindowtest.h. This seems to have solved my problem, thank you very much for the assistance. I will to implement a destructor for the forms, as you recommended.

Comment: In addition to the destructor you should do a thing like in my edit

Comment: Skip the `if(mForm)`.  http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/freestore-mgmt.html#faq-16.8

Comment: You can use a std::unique_ptr<dialog> instead of plain pointer to dialog. It will take care of deallocation of the old form when you are assigning a new one or when the main window is destructed (the destructor of the unique_ptr is called).

Answer (score 2):

In your mywindowtest.hpp you have to declare the pointer first:

```
// mytestwindow.hpp
// ...
private:
    dialog* mForm;
// ...

// mytestwindow.cpp
void mWindowTest::openNewWindow()
{
    mForm = new dialog (this);
    form->show();
}
```

Or you declare it directly in your cpp, but then it is no member and only known in `openNewWindow()`.

```
void mWindowTest::openNewWindow()
{
    dialog* form = new dialog (this);
    form->show();
}
```

When you work with Qt you should know the basics of C++. This example is one of those basics. Use Google and read some stuff about pointer tutorials and dynamic memory allocation.

Hope that helps. :)